# How to have a image fade out without another div

Tags: html, css, image, border-shadow

I have a page that has lists of products with their images. When I hover on an image, I have the image enlarge slightly, but the `max-height` does not change. Because of this, I want to have the image fade out on all four sides. Currently, I am using a white background but ideally the fade out would be done by reducing `opacity` instead of white. The issue I am having is that the image is clickable, so I cannot use another div on top of it to create the fade effect. How can I use CSS on an image to do this?

HTML:

```
<li class="product">
    <article class="card ">
<figure class="card-figure">
    <a href="/audio-technica-pro-31/">
        <img class="card-image lazyautosizes lazyloaded" data-sizes="auto" src="https://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/server2400/7659a/images/stencil/500x659/products/1190/1191/pro_31_1__34951.1294215822.jpg?c=2" data-src="https://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/server2400/7659a/images/stencil/500x659/products/1190/1191/pro_31_1__34951.1294215822.jpg?c=2" alt="Audio Technica PRO 31" title="Audio Technica PRO 31" sizes="58px">
    </a>
    <figcaption class="card-figcaption">
        <div class="card-figcaption-body">
                    <a href="#" class="button button--small card-figcaption-button quickview" data-product-id="1190">Quick view</a>
                <label class="button button--small card-figcaption-button" for="compare-1190">
                    Compare <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="1190" id="compare-1190" data-compare-id="1190">
                </label>
                        <a href="/cart.php?action=add&amp;product_id=1190" class="button button--small card-figcaption-button">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
<div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text" data-test-info-type="brandName">Audio Technica</p>
    <h4 class="card-title">
        <a href="/audio-technica-pro-31/">Audio Technica PRO 31</a>
    </h4>

    <div class="card-text" data-test-info-type="price">
                    <div class="price-section price-section--withoutTax ">
        <span data-product-price-without-tax="" class="price price--withoutTax">$52.99</span>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card{
    &:hover{
        .card-image{
            opacity:.75;
            transform: scale(1.05);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could the `img` be replaced by a div with `background-image` property?

Comment: @ovokuro No, that would not work. I am using a design from an e-commerce site that is generating that part for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```css
.card-image {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.card-image:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

Comment: That does not make the edges fade out, my issue is that at the top of the image the image is being cut off so there is just a line where is ends, this only reduces the opacity. Thank you though for the idea of `transition`, this makes it look much nicer.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood...so you mean fading out the edges?

then try: box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 80px 90px rgba(255,255,255,1);

play around with the blur (80px) and the spread (90px)

Comment: Perfect for what I needed for a simple fade on a linked image.  If an image is linked, simply add this style to the <a href="" class="card-image">  to get the fade. Too many other solutions involve multiple added divs.